# SGE : Prioritize some tasks of a job

Tags: cluster-computing, qsub, sungridengine

I have a job array where the load of each task isn't well balanced. 
The last task will take about 5 times longer to execute than other tasks, so I would want to **execute this task before others** to avoid waiting after this task to finish (using only one slot...).

How can I do that ?

I already tried increasing the priority of the last task using :
**qalter -p 100 *job_id* -t *task_id***
But I get the following error : *"denied: the selected option works only on jobs and not on tasks"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tasks of a job can be put on hold with the command **qalter -h** and the option **-t**.

So, a way to prioritize some task would be to put on hold all other task until the tasks to prioritize have started.

Example : if we want to put on hold the tasks of the job 30500 that are on the queue except the last one (100):
**qalter -h u 30500 -t 1:99**

Then, when the task 100 started, we can remove the hold with:
**qalter -h U 30500 -t 1:99**